# How are the matrix values calculated in Octave when we divide a scalar with a vector?

Tags: vectorization, octave, scalar

I am starting to use Octave and I am trying to understand how is the underlying calculation done for dividing a Scalar by vector ?

I am able to understand how ./ is operating to give us the results - dividing 1 by every element of the matrix column. However, I am not able to get my head around how we get the values in the second case ? 1 / (1 + a)

```
Example :
 g = 1 ./ (1 + a)
g =

   0.50000
   0.25000
   0.20000

>> g = 1 / (1 + a)
g =

   0.044444   0.088889   0.111111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide 1 by a vector, it gives you a vector that yields 1 when multiplied on the left by the first vector. In this sense, it is a sort of 'inverse' of the vector, although it will only be a one way inverse. In your example:

```
>> (1/(1+a))*(1+a)
ans =  1
>> (1+a)*(1/(1+a))
ans =

0.088889   0.177778   0.222222
0.177778   0.355556   0.444444
0.222222   0.444444   0.555556
```

You could say `1/(1+a)` is the left inverse of `1+a`. This would also explain why the dimensions of the vector are transposed. Another way to put it: given a vector `v`, `1/v` is the solution (`w`) of the vector equation `w*v=1`.

Comment: **Another way to put it: given a vector v, 1/v is the solution (w) of the vector equation w*v=1** helped to better understand . Thanks !

Comment: Although I was thinking that that inverse wouldn't always be unique, so I still don't know exactly how all three numbers relate, but at least that gives some insight into the problem.